# How to change format 00:00 to 0:00, datetime

Tags: python, datetime, format

I need to change the format to compare the time to bot send the message, i think it's just change the format strptime() to strftime() or vice-versa, but i dkn how do this, and i want to send this message with the discord bot, but i think it's wrong because if i test just the code of discord bot the (WHILE TRUE:) stop

````
import discord
from datetime import datetime, date
import datetime
import requests
from time import sleep
import time

url = 'https://www.bdohelper.me/gamez/schedule/EU'
params = dict()
TOKEN = ""
while True:
    resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
    data = resp.json()
    boss = data[0]['boss']
    time_spawn = data[0]['spawnat']
    channel = data[0]['channel']
    time_spawn = time_spawn.split('T')
    time_spawn = time_spawn.pop(1)
    time_spawn = time_spawn.split('.')
    time_spawn = time_spawn.pop(0)
    time_spawn = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_spawn, '%H:%M:%S').time()
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    now = datetime.datetime.strptime(now, '%H:%M:%S').time()
    until_spawn = datetime.datetime.combine(date.today(), time_spawn) - datetime.datetime.combine(date.today(), now)
    print(until_spawn)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    for_spawn = datetime.time()
    print(for_spawn)
    if time_spawn == for_spawn:
        def sendMessage(message):
            client = discord.Client()

            @client.event
            async def on_ready():
                channel = client.get_channel(MY CHANNEL ID)
                await channel.send(message)
                print("done")

                client.run(TOKEN)

            if __name__ == '__main__':

                sendMessage(time_spawn)```
OUTPUT:
0:04:21  <------- change
00:05:45
````

Comment: Instead of messing around manually trying to adjust `time_spawn`, use [`dateparser.parse()`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on the `"spawnat"` field directly. That will output a `datetime.datetime` which you can then format however you want.

Comment: THXXXXX hahahha thxx

Comment: actually you don't need a third party library either; you can parse `time_spawn` to a datetime object conveniently like `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(time_spawn.replace('Z', '+00:00'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (inserted hyphen between % and H):

```
time_spawn = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_spawn, '%-H:%M:%S').time()
```

That generally removes leading zeroes when formatting datetimes.